# Redux componentDidUpdate use next props

Tags: reactjs, redux

What is the best practice for deriving data in `componentDidUpdate`, pushing that into the redux store, but also then using that data to further derive more data, and again push that into the redux store?

Given redux is synchronous, I was hoping to be able to access the updated store straight after I done the dispatch, but I am assuming that because it is still within the componentDidUpdate, props would not have been updated with the new store data via `mapStateToProps`.  i.e. I tried -

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    this.determineAndStoreA()
    this.doSomethingElse(this.props.A) // hoping this would be the updated A
}
```

`this.props.A` is the old value still

should I being something more like -

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    const a = this.determineA()
    this.storeA(a);
    this.doSomethingElse(a) // using a local copy of A
}
```

With some further digging, I found a similar question in https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/291 . Dan recommends to react to the action in the reducer, but that feels like I now have to combine the logic of determining A, determining B from A, storing A and B at same time?

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about what you are doing in `determineA`. This whole setup seems like a code smell. It seems that the action that caused this update was only partially handled by your reducer and now you have your component doing another step of the work and dispatching to your reducers. I would look into whether you can have your reducers take care of this fully in one step rather than delegating part of the work back to a component.

Comment: thats a fair comment, i've added a little more to my question.  I think you could be right, i'll take a another pass and see if the logic can be combined and handled in one redux action / reducer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you are struggling with. First let me try to describe more fully the scenario I think you are dealing with.

You have `A` and `B` in your store. `C` is derived from `A` and `B`, so if `A` changes, you want to re-derive `C` and put it in your store. You could then have component prop `E` that is derived from `C` and `D`. Action `x` changes `A` and now you need the new value for `C` or `E` and it is difficult to do it in one step without making the reducers overly complicated.

There are three main approaches I have used for scenarios like this and which one I would recommend depends on the specifics of the scenario. All of these are just different approaches for how/when/where to determine `C` (and could be extended to further derivations like `E`).

**Approach 1**
Calculate `C` in middleware designed for dealing with side effects of actions.

This is the approach most similar to what you already have. It just moves it out of a component so you aren't fighting against the interaction between your store and when lifecycle methods receive the new information. For this approach, I would use Redux Saga and have it handle calculating `C` in response to action `x` and dispatching the action to update the store with the new value for `C`. It's easy to do this (if you're past the initial Redux Saga learning curve) since Redux Saga receives the action after the store has already been updated. The main downside of this approach is that your store will temporarily be in an inconsistent state where `C` doesn't yet reflect the change to `A`. For some scenarios this matters and for some it doesn't. The other potential downside is that if you aren't already using Redux Saga, it can be a little intimidating at first because the use of generator functions and `yield` and the whole mindset when using Redux Saga can feel a bit alien (but I really love using Redux Saga for complex async scenarios).

**Approach 2** Calculate `C` in an action creator.

This generally involves using a thunk for the initial response to action `x` and the thunk can then get `B` from the store, calculate `C` and dispatch an action with a payload that contains two pieces -- one used by the reducer for `A` and one used by the reducer for `C`. The main downside with this approach is if there are multiple ways that the dependencies for `C` (i.e. `A` and `B`) can change, this can become a complicated way to organize things, but for some scenarios it can work fine. I have mostly moved away from this approach in favor of the other two approaches.

**Approach 3** Don't put `C` in your store.

If `C` is fully derived from other things in your store, then it doesn't really need to be in the store. `C` is just a view on other information in your store. You can use a selector for this purpose instead. If it is expensive to derive `C`, then use a memoized selector. In the more complicated case of also having `E` that is derived from `C` and `D`, a selector for `E` can leverage the selector for `C` while getting `D` from the store. This is the approach I generally favor unless there is a compelling reason for `C` to be in the store. This approach allows your reducers to stay simple and independent while keeping your store in a consistent state.

**Other Approaches**

There are other ways to do this, but the 3 approaches above are ones I have actually used myself. One other route is to have a reducer that leverages other reducers. In this approach, the reducers for `A` and `B` would be used by a reducer that then computes `C` and returns state with all three pieces of information. There are packages out there for making it easier to compose reducers in this manner, but I haven't used them because I'm not very interested in this approach. For me, it just feels like the wrong place to put this complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get the updated prop in the same cycle as Redux pushes the value in to the store and triggers another update to the component.

Do you really need to trigger both actions from componentDidUpdate?

What you can do is create a new action that is triggered from the action where you stored your A value.

something like this

```
store.dispatch(saveValueA()).then(() =>
  doSomeAction()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component will be rerender everytimes `A` would change, and `componentDidUpdate` will be called.

You can then do something like :

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){

    const hasAChanged = this.props.A !=== prevprops.A;

    if (hasAChanged) {
        this.determineAndStoreA()
    } else {
        this.doSomethingElse(this.props.A)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what you'r trying to do, hope it helps.